# IF formula contains certain text for entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas

So for this excel file, I need to calculate a percent for one subject which has several rows. With this, I have thus come up with:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH("b0021",B3:B14)), (SUM(T3:T14))/12, "no")

Column B Column T
b0021     1        
b0021     0
...       
b0025     1
```

However, this does not seem to work, as to search that ALL the cells contain this text (right now it looks that at least one cell contains the text, which is not what I want to do if it should be one for the subject).

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: @pnuts yes, and then for the next row it would be "no" (as I want to drag this formula down the entire column)

Comment: @pnuts Yes, then I would manually change it for the next subjects

Comment: @pnuts No, this still seems to account that "b0021" as being within the row, rather than seeing that if one of the subject numbers is not correct as being "no"

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your cell and press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make it array formula
Your formula =COUNT(SEARCH("b0021",B3:B14)) would start showing result only if it's in brackets

```
{=COUNT(SEARCH("b0021",B3:B14))}
```

In other words just add { } to make it formula array or by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter while editing your formula

```
{=IF(COUNT(SEARCH("b0021",B3:B14)), (SUM(T3:T14))/12, "no")}
```

It looks from your formula that you would need to use =SUMIFS formula rather than what you have:

```
=SUMIFS(T3:T14,B3:B14,"b0021")/SUM(T3:T14)
```

Comment: No, that seems to give me the same results; not accounting for ALL subjects having a certain number

Comment: Perhaps you need to break it down your formula into 2 parts {=COUNT(SEARCH("b0021",B3:B14))} and the remaining average. I'm not really clear what type of calculation you'd like to perform but your first part with Count would start counting only if it's array in { }.

Comment: =SUMIFS(T3:T14,B3:B14,"b0021")/SUM(T3:T14) is this what you  want in your result?

Comment: No, that also does not account that all the rows contain the subject number